# GoogleMap - animateCamera() doing nothing after Fragment resume

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I'm using a GoogleMap/MapView in a layout, but as a View not a Fragment (because the parent needs to be a Fragment), so the fragment's layout includes this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

The Fragment contains this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    <......>
    initMap(bundle, mapView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApp.bus.register(this);
    updateMapLocation(MyApp.getMostRecentLocation());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MyApp.bus.unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void locationReceived(LocationReceived m) {
    Timber.i("Received bus message - Location!");
    updateMapLocation(MyApp.getMostRecentLocation());
}
```

Its parent Fragment contains this:

```
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mapView!=null) {
        mapView.onResume();
        map = this.mapView.getMap();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mapView!=null) mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    if (mapView!=null) mapView.onLowMemory();
}

protected void initMap(Bundle bundle, MapView mapView) {
    this.mapView = mapView;
    this.mapView.onCreate(bundle);
    map = this.mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error initialising Google Map");
    }
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MyApp.getCentralUKLatLng(), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.map_zoom_initial));
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mapView!=null) mapView.onPause();
}

protected void updateMapLocation(Location location) {
    Timber.i("Moving map to a new location: " + location);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

New locations are being delivered via an Otto bus. The code above works perfectly, but ONLY the first time. If I open another fragment in front of this one, and then close it again, the map fails to animate to subsequently provided locations. The locations are definitely received, the animateCamera() method is definitely called (with a valid location and zoom) but absolutely nothing happens. No error, no log message, nothing. What makes it even more infuriating is on one Fragment (which is identical to the code above) it works fine when resuming the Fragment.

I assume I am doing something wrong with how the GoogeMap or the MapView is being (re)initialised on resume, but I'm passing through the onPause() and onResume() calls to the MapView which I understand is necessary. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I think you have altered the code too much... The fragment calls initMap but that is defined in what you call the "parent" fragment. Are there two fragments? Something is getting lost when you try to register/unregister when the 2nd map is closed.

Comment: "... as a View not a Fragment (because the parent needs to be a Fragment)" why not use nested fragments?

Comment: @peguerosdc I think you can't put the MapFragment in the XML layout file and inflate it in a fragment. If you want to use a MapFragment inside another Fragment you have to create it programmatically.

Comment: You should use [`MapView.getMapAsync`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) instead of `MapView.getMap` and null-check for map in `updateMapLocation`. This will probably not solve your issue though.

Comment: Maybe you can try to add a callback to your GoogleMap.animate method and see if the animation is complete or cancelled.

Comment: Use `MapView.getMapAsync` and you're guaranteed to receive a correct `GoogleMap` instance. If not the callback won't be invoked at all. Don't store a `GoogleMap` instance in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have not write the code in onResume().
See when you open and close the second fragment the first fragment will always stay there so when the second fragment gets closed the onResume() of first will get called.
So you have to animate the camera in onResume().

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I have confirmed that onResume() is not called and checking the docs this is correct behaviour in this scenario. I open the fragment containing the map, then a another fragment, then close that second fragment. My map fragment becomes visible again, but onResume() is not called and I expect this is wju the map is not working correctly. onResume would only be called if the Activity onResume is called, and it is not as both fragments are within the same activity.

Comment: Sincere apologies for the slow reply and my failure to manage the bounty, I was not able to get online. I'm marking your answer as correct as it led me to the solution. The problem was that onResume was not being called, because onResume is ONLY called on a fragment if onResume is called on the Activity. In this case there was one Activity, two Fragments, and as the Activity did not resume, neither did the Fragment.